# Consume a Kafka Topic every hour using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I want to consume a Kafka topic as a batch where I want to read Kafka topic hourly and read the latest hourly data.

```scala
val readStream = existingSparkSession
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
  .option("subscribe", "kafka.raw")
  .load()
```

But this always read first 20 data rows and these rows are starting from the very beginning so this never pick latest data rows.

How can I read the latest rows on a hourly basis using scala and spark?

Comment: Why do you want to do batch processing through kafka? isnt it available somewhere in your data lake?

Answer (score 2):

If you read Kafka messages in Batch mode you need to take care of the bookkeeping which data is new and which is not yourself. Remember that Spark will not commit any messages back to Kafka, so every time you restart the batch job it will read from beginning (or based on the setting `startingOffsets` which defaults to `earliest` for batch queries.

For your scenario where you want to run the job once every hour and only process the new data that arrived to Kafka in the previous hour, you can make use of the writeStream trigger option `Trigger.Once` for streaming queries.

There is a nice [blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html) from Databricks that nicely explains why a streaming query with `Trigger.Once` should be preferred over a batch query.

The main point being:

> "When you’re running a batch job that performs incremental updates, you generally have to deal with figuring out what data is new, what you should process, and what you should not. Structured Streaming already does all this for you."

Make sure that you also set the option "checkpointLocation" in your writeStream. In the end, you can have a simple cron job that submits your streaming job once an hour.

Comment: Is there also a way to read the data between fixed hour intervals, like 7am - 8am?